# Create a custom NANT file with C#

Tags: c#, build, nant

I want to create custom NANT files. To do this, I use C# to create a ".build" file using the input from the user, I wish to create a custom build. I already have a build file, but each time I'm making a new project I have to create a new build file, so I would like only to input some information into a C# form and then the file would be auto-generated.

I tried with XmlTextWriter witch works fine for the header of my build file, but I get problems when I get to line like this :

```
<property name= "name" value = "test"/> .
```

With XmlTextWriter line are like this :

```
<description>This is a test.</description> .
```

So I wonder how could I write my NANT script.

It doesn't have to be with XmlTextWrite ...

- EDIT -

I found a way:

```
textWriter.WriteRaw("<property name = \"project.name\" value=\"" + projectName + "\" />");
```

result :

```
<property name = "project.name" value="test" />
```

I have to enter it "raw", but it's better than nothing. I'm still open to a better way to do it!

Thanks!

Comment: What if the projectName has a special character in it... such as >, <, &, ', ", etc.?  Try to use a built in class like XmlTextWriter (as you mention) because it will do the escaping for you

Comment: WriteRaw takes the special character. But you answer is still a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend against handcrafting your own XML through a non-XML specific text writer.  This will cause pain with escaping characters, among other things.

I might be missing something, but you should be able to use `XmlTextWriter` for this.  This is untested but you should get the general idea:

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(...);

writer.StartDocument();

writer.WriteStartElement("property");
writer.WriteAttributeString("name", "project.name");
writer.WriteAttributeString("value", projectName);
writer.WriteEndElement();

writer.EndDocument();
writer.Close();
```

Comment: also depending on what your goal is, you might have success rolling your own nant extension instead of dynamically generating build files